# InRelease failure for Docker caused Software Updater issue

Tags: apt, updates, docker

I asked a question on a failing Software Update due to a "not paid" issue and a gatekeeper rejected/closed my question. Evidently, the problem is that docker requires/expects/uses a repository that is not valid at this time and has had issues in the past as explained in

[Stretch apt update failing, missing InRelease file on mirrors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478309/stretch-apt-update-failing-missing-inrelease-file-on-mirrors)

For anyone familiar with docker, what is the workaround for the above?  Or is docker now dependent upon a "for fee" respository?  If one of the gatekeepers for this list is going to reject/close/disallow/claim redundancy for this question, please help me rephrase it to pass gatekeeper control and find the workaround.  docker is required by some of the environment I use.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that /apt/get has subdirectories in which repository URLs are stored that are not displayed in the GUI Software Update repository editing screens. `sudo grep cloud /etc/apt/*/*` found the directories/files with the issue (cloud was a regular expression that appeared in the diagnostic from the Software Updater GUI) and then as root (sudo) I commented-out the offending URL repository.